# Javascriptの仕様で「オブジェクトは共有渡しで、プリミティブ値は値渡し」と区別しているのか

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptの参照に関する記事でよく、オブジェクトは共有渡しで、プリミティブ値は値渡しと書かれていますが、仕様書をみても当該の記述を見つけられません。
仕様書を読む限り区別がない、つまり全てが値渡しの様に見えてしまいます。

もしくはReference型にbaseとして格納されているのは値を構成するデータ配列ではなく、値の存在そのもの、つまり参照（ポインタ）に近い概念であって、結局実は全部が共有渡しということなのでしょうか？

例えばProperty Accessorsの仕様で
「Return a value of type Reference whose base value is bv」
というのは、作成されるReferenceのbaseにbvそのものを格納する→bvをデータとして複製して格納ではなく、その存在そのものを格納→実際は参照（ポインタ）に当たるものが格納されるイメージ、というニュアンスなのでしょうか？

Comment: 「オブジェクトは参照の値渡し」と「プリミティブ値は値渡し」と併記されていると混乱してきます。前者は「オブジェクトは参照渡し」ではダメなのでしょうか?

Comment: その言い回しについて議論があることは知っていますが、ここではそのことについて深く掘り下げるつもりはありません。  
「参照の値渡し」、「共有渡し」、もしくはJS界での「参照渡し」のどれと読み違えてもらっても構いません。

Comment: わかりにくいので「共有渡し」に統一しました

Comment: せっかくの良質問ですので、可能なら「まとめ回答」みたいなのが欲しいですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まとめると、JSで値が何かの変数にセットされるような書き方がされているときは、  値がコピーされて箱に入れられるようなイメージではなく、新しい名前に値が結び付けられるイメージが良いということでしょうね。

しかし、やはり「値渡し」という言い方をすると、データとしてコピーされて新しいエリアに書かれるようなイメージがあります。Wikipediaの項目を見ても、そのようなイメージで書いてあると思います。
実際に仕様の細部を実装側で補完して、参照の値渡しなどで実装することも出来そうですが、
あくまで仕様の範囲で語るのであれば、そもそもデータが渡っていくという考え方自体が良くないのかもしれないと思いました。

きっと値という存在に対する名付けの連鎖と捉えるのが一番素直なのかもしれません。
そうすると、渡すのではなく、むしろ「名前貰い」と言った感じになるのでしょうかね。

Answer (score 2):

引数の動作については、JavaScript が実装している ECMAScript の仕様書がある程度参考になるかと思います。
以下の様な箇所で触れられています。

- http://alpha.mixi.co.jp/entry/2012/10796/#ecma-263-3-8-introduction
- http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1

ECMA263-3 の第八章内にある「ECMAScript での実装」にも書かれている通り、全ては共有渡し（Call by sharing）です。

質問で @JSer さんがおっしゃっているとおりの理解で間違いないかと思います。

Comment: やはり全て共有渡しで正しそうということですね。ありがとうございます。  
ただ疑問残りとしては、ES仕様書原本内に、「Call by sharing」や「値を持つ」という言葉の定義についてはっきりした記述が見当たらないことです。    

>ECMA263-3 の第八章内にある「ECMAScript での実装」にも書かれている通り     
ES3仕様書の8章は「Types」です。    
仕様書に実装に関するそれらの記述は見当たりません。

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.4

を見ると、関数に渡る引数はそのリストを評価した際に`GetValue()`をかましていて、いわゆる共有渡しの手順になっていると思うのですが、それでは不足でしょうか。

Comment: 「関数評価戦略」で独立して記述されるのではなく、引数リストの作成(=assign) として記述されてそうですね。その意味では [GetValue(8.7.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) がほぼ根幹っぽいです。

Comment: GetValueは（構造体チックな存在だと思われる）Reference型値の殻を剥く作業であって、本当の根幹ではないと思います。
根幹は、Referenceのbeseに値がセットされる時のされ方は、値のデータ配列の複製というより参照のイメージで書かれているのかということではないでしょうか？
それは置いておいても結局、全てが共有渡しということであるならば、よく書かれる「プリミティブ型は値渡しだけどオブジェクトは～」の説明は、仕様から最も素直に考えられる仕組みの説明としては不適切だと思われますか？

Comment: @JSer すみません。前半の部分は自分ではちょっとよくわかりませんでした。/ GetValue(V)はVがReferenceでない場合は単にVを返すとあるので、「プリミティブ型(というかいわゆる値)は値渡し」という部分は問題ないと考えます。

Comment: ReferenceかReferenceでないかと、プリミティブかプリミティブでないかは一致しません。
GetValue時にReferenceでないというのはほぼ、ソースコードにリテラルで書かれているケースを示しています。
例えばa=1とa={}でのGetValueにはNumber型とObject型が渡されます。
そしてb=aとした時にはaが1でも{}でもGetValueではReference型が渡されます。

Comment: GetValueとPutValue、それとValueに関する記述を探して見ると、そもそもValueの複製を取るという概念自体が存在しませんよね。なのでJSにおけるValueを他の言語の「値」と同等に考えること自体が誤りなのでしょう。それと「参照渡し」「値渡し」っていうのは、あくまでも現象の理解の助けになるように選ばれた用語であって、言語仕様を正確に示すものではないですし。

Comment: そうですね。
この質問をした根底として、「仕様の説明は簡潔にしたとしても、できるだけ仕様書に対し嘘をつかないようにしたい」という目的がありました。
複製するように書かれていないということは、プリミティブ値のやり取りであっても同じものを指していると捉えたほうが自然と考え、プリミティブとオブジェクトでわざわざ扱いが違うかように書かれている巷の解説に違和感を感じました。
それでもしそれが正しいとすれば、概念を説明するときはオブジェクトを特別扱いせずに、全て共有渡しと言った方が良いのでは無いかというのが私の主張です。

Comment: やっと合点がいきました。ただそうするとちょっと「共有渡し」という言葉も、数値(プリミティブ)に対して使っちゃうと、他の言語からの類推でかなり不自然なことになりませんかね。プリミティブのValue(=共有)はimmutable、ObjectのValue(のプロパティ)はmutable、みたいな説明を付け足す必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 2):

まず、ご存じだと思いますが JavaScript にはオブジェクトの実体を指し示せる変数は存在しません。あるのはオブジェクトの参照を保持出来る変数です。

```
var a = new Human(); // new した Human 参照を a で保持
a = new Cat();       // Cat のオブジェクト参照へ切り替える
```

**参照** という物は VM 内では一意となります。この一意の値を意味して値渡しという表記されたり記述されたりしているのだと思います。

もちろん、参照されているオブジェクトのプロパティが関数呼び出し時にコピーされる訳ではありませんので、そういう意味では共有渡しと表現される場合もあります。

参照型という表現が出来るならば、それはプリミティブ型と言えますね。

**追記**

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/#call-by-sharing

> Regardless the fact that the concept of the reference in this case appears, this strategy should not be treated as call by reference (though, in this case the majority makes a mistake), because the value of the argument is not the direct alias, but the copy of the address.

この部分が仕様と思われます。

Comment: それを、仕様書のどこを読めばそうだと言えるのか、その確信が欲しいのです。
例えばオブジェクトの参照を保持というのは、要はオブジェクトは変数に間接的に結び付けられているということですよね。
ではどこでその間接的な結びつきができ得るかというと、自分の読む限りはReferenceのbaseと、値データバイナリの間だと思い、１つの疑問はこれがあっているのかどうか。
そして、そうであるとすると、オブジェクト型とその他の型の参照に関する扱いの差は見受けられないので、実は全ての型において間接的な結びつきがなされていると考えるのが最も自然なのではないかというのが、２つ目の疑問です。

Comment: 追記より：それは公式の仕様ではなく有志による解説です。
私が仕様と言っているのは、こういったもののことです。
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: ですと 3100 さんの仰られている GetValue の `is Reference` の部分だと思います。

Comment: つまりどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: 読みましたが、はっきりと明記されている箇所を見つける事は出来ませんでした。MDN等では call-by-shareing という文言で書かれていましたが、pdf中では`if type(ref) is reference then return value` の様な記述だけですね。

Comment: それはReference型かどうかの判定ですよね。
Reference型は一見参照を実現するような構造に見えますが、これが変数やオブジェクトプロパティの値として格納されて使われることはありません。あくまで変数や関数実行時のthis等を解決するための、「どのような環境でどこをどのように参照しようとしたか」の途中形式であって、～渡しなどというのには関係しないと思います。

Comment: はい。その意味で pdf からは見つける事が出来なかったと書かせて頂きました。ただ一つ、これは関数の引数部分として読むのではなく、argList (配列)の1要素にオブジェクトを差し込んだ時にどう動くかという見方をすると、配列への1要素変更はコピーではないという読み方が出来てつまりは call-by-shareing と理解できると思います。

Comment: そうですね。ここまでの皆様の回答のお陰で、コピーではなくcall-by-shareingという点にはずいぶん確信を持つことが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

まず、参照渡し、値渡しと分けて考えなくても良いのではないでしょうか。
考えると混乱するだけです。

ほとんどのプログラミング言語での関数呼び出しに対する、私の理解は、

「**全て値渡しをする。**」

であり、Javascript 言語について特別なことは、

「**変数自体のアドレス値を扱う指定がない**」

という特徴があるだけです。この理解の仕方で納得できるでしょうか？

Javascript では、オブジェクトを引数として関数が呼び出される時に、実際はオブジェクトを指し示すアドレス値が渡されることになります。変数（入れ物）のアドレス値を渡すような指定はできません。プリミティブ型（文字以外）の場合でも、変数の中身が渡されます。これも変数自体のアドレス値を渡すことになる指定はできません。「変数にオブジェクトが入っている」とは実質オブジェクトを指すアドレス値が入っているとみなせ、関数にオブジェクトを渡すとは、オブジェクトを指すアドレス値を渡すことと言えます。くどいようですが変数を渡すことではありません。

混乱の原因は言語によって、「XXX 渡し」の言葉の意味するところが変わることです。参照渡し、共有渡しなどの言葉は、それぞれのプログラミング言語での記述の概念を理解しやすくするための言い回しと考える程度でよく、世の中には、値しかない、と割り切ったほうが理解がしやすいかと考えます。 （共有が参照渡しと違うのは、アドレス値が複製される、ということだけでしょうか、そこがもやもやします。）

※文字(string)型はオブジェクトと同じように扱われます。
※ここではポインタに相当するものをアドレス値と呼んでいます。（メモリ上のアドレスの値そのままということではない）
※ ここで扱うプリミティブ型とは、`boolean`, `string` と `number` であり、`null` と `undefined` を除く。

> 例えばProperty Accessorsの仕様で 「Return a value of type Reference whose base
>   value is bv」
>   というのは、作成されるReferenceのbaseにbvそのものを格納する→bvをデータとして複製して格納ではなく、その存在そのものを格納→実際は参照（ポインタ）に当たるものが格納されるイメージ、というニュアンスなのでしょうか？

原文からは、「複製」や「作成」や「格納」という言葉を読み取れませんでした。私には Javascript を使ってメタに書けば以下のような感じで理解できただけです。

```
return Reference({
    base_value       : by,        // MemberExpression からの値
    referenced_name  : nameValue, // IdentifierReference からの値
    strict_reference : true,      // true か false
})
```

#### 追記:

調べたら、関連するものがありました。共有だか参照だかを述べた日本語訳のある「[詳細 ECMA-262-3](http://alpha.mixi.co.jp/category/ECMA-262-3)」と同じ方が書かれたもので、「[ECMA-262-5 in Detail](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/#name-binding)」 の中の記述です。

> Think about bindings not as by-reference, but (from C viewpoint) as
>   by-pointer (or sometimes — by-sharing) operation. Often it’s also
>   called as a special case of by-value where value is an address.
>   Assignment just changes (rebinds) the pointer’s value (the address)
>   from one memory block to another. And when we assign one variable to
>   another we just copy the address of the same object to the second
>   variable. Now two identifiers are said to share the one object. From
>   here the name — by-sharing.

参考: [ECMA-262-5 in detail. Chapter 3.2. Lexical environments: ECMAScript implementation.](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/#name-binding)

まだ、なんかこう、もやもや感がのこる・・・

それよりも、ここでは変数がオブジェクトを保持することを、"Name-Binding"とも説明しているのが興味深いですね。変数にオブジェクトを「代入」ではなく「リバインディング」とも言っています。変数名にオブジェクトがバインドされているという概念なんですって。イメージとしては、バインドほうが余計な先入観がなく、説明によいかもしれないと思いました。

Comment: つまり、オブジェクトの実態、オブジェクトが扱われる時はデータ列ではなくアドレスということですね。そしてプリミティブ型は文字列以外データ列（＋型情報）そのものがコピーされながらやりとりされると。
これは実装側に立った考えとして大変納得できます。ですが私が疑問に思っているのは、仕様書にそういった記述がハッキリ書かれている部分が見当たらないことです。
仕様書ではそういった区別があるように書かれているように見えません。
そうであるなら、例えば数値型等も含めて全てがアドレスで管理されている、共有渡しであるというイメージ以外に、仕様書の書き方と現実実装とでつじつまが合う解釈は無いのでは無いかと思いました。
とにかく、常識や実装からではなく、仕様書のどこどのように解釈すれば最も確信を持ってJSの参照、値の受け渡し周りの振る舞いについて語れるかを知りたいのです。

Comment: アドレスとかを言い出すと具体的な話になりますが、
何が言いたいかというと、要はES仕様で仮に「A value is X」と書かれている時の概念としては、A値としてXと同じ形の実物が複製されて入るのではなく、あくまでXの存在自体が入るのではないかと思いました。
であるならば、例えば「a = 1; b = a」とした時のaとbは、同じ形のデータというよりむしろ、同じ存在を持っているということになると思います。
プリミティブ値はイミュータブルであり、また参照先を書き換えられないJSではどちらで捉えても挙動は変わりませんが、一般に言われているプリミティブ型はオブジェクトと区別されてコピーされていくというイメージではないように思います。
そういった仕様のイメージを一番簡単な具体的な実装形で説明するのであれば、全てが共有渡しといえるのではないかと思いました。

Comment: JSer さん、コメントありがとうございます。私は、「共有渡し」の特別な点を考えようとしましたが、もやもやのまま失敗したのでこのような回答になりました。全体としての説明は、 Wikipedia の Evaluation Strategy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy  (ECMA-262-3 in Detail 日本語訳での言及もこちらを参考にされています) をまずチェックしました。仕様に書かれている事柄は、抽象的な説明のみでしょうから、「～渡し」ということには言及していないのかもしれませんね。実装でどうするかは、実装側に任されていると思いますし、その自由な部分で悩んでいるのではないかという印象を持ちました。

Comment: 仕様に書かれているのは抽象的なことというのはまさにそうだと思います。別のものだとGCについても書かれていませんし、実装する側が考えて工夫すべき点が多いように思います。
バインドという概念は大変しっくり来ました。もやもや感がずいぶん晴れたような気がします。ありがとうございます。